Why the results for combining and solving systems of linear equations a = b: no solutions. Reasoning. Thanks.
Part1
Part2
Apparently I don't have permissions to post pictures so Stack Exchange converted my png files into their own web hosted links. The links are shares to LaTeX documents where I ask my question. Thanks.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

Thanks for the clarification Carl. I suppose I'll go ahead and rewrite the question using MathJax. Thanks.
